# Date issue when using New Date () android

Tags: android, date, time

I am writing to you to see if someone can guide me what is happening with this code ...

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");

Date datofecha1 = new Date (time1);
String datotexto1 = formatter.format(datofecha1);
System.out.println(datotexto1);
```

the long of time1, I am fetching it from my cloud firebase database, it is an item number 1597081737457

That code should print me:

```
I/System.out: 10.08.2020, 13:48:57
```

but it prints me

```
I/System.out: 31.12.1969, 20:00:00
```

IF I change the long in my database, it gives me another date to print, it always prints December 31, 1969, a total madness (whatever the length I put on it).

As a curious fact if I put the long direct to the code in this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");

Date datofecha1 = new Date (1597081737457L);
String datotexto1 = formatter.format(datofecha1);
System.out.println(datotexto1);
```

In the following way if the date prints me perfect

As a curious fact in the database, I can only put a number for the long, I can't put the final L, which must be put for the long, and I'm really stuck trying to print the date of the long used, and not that date of December 31 that always puts me.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data stored in a Firebase is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener. You have to use value inside listener or ensure the listener is triggered before

Comment: I'm going to use the code inside the listener and I'll tell you what happens, I think there could be the solution, thanks

Comment: Hello, thanks to your suggestion I have been able to solve my problem, I have moved all the code into the addOnSuccessListener listener where I receive the data from the database, and perfect, everything works correctly, so you have helped me with your solution, thank you, thank you